# Rails convention for method in multiple controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

I have an app that has users whose profiles are accessible via site.com/username. When choosing a username, I make an AJAX call to a method in my UsersController to make sure the username is available (and check on the back end as well when submitted). I now want to add groups that will also be accessible through site.com/groupname. Since group and user names cannot collide, whatever controller method that responds to the AJAX call will need to check both so the check_username_available and check_groupname_available methods will do the exact same thing. What's the best practice / Rails way to handle this since I don't want to replicate code in both UsersController and GroupsController?

Having a method for each controller seems a bit redundant, even if the functionality is pulled out to a helper, since there will still be two routes that do the same thing. Having a separate controller solves the problem too but not sure this is good Rails practice.

Answer (score 4):

code that is reused can be shared via a module

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  include NameUniqueness
end

class GroupsController < ActionController::Base
  include NameUniqueness
end

module NameUniqueness
  protected
  def check_name
    # implementation here
  end
end
```

both controllers will now have access the check_name instance method.

Answer (score 0):

DanPickett's answer is great.

Another choice is to make a class method in the user model and just call it from each controller.  Since this name checking seems like a job for the model, that's what I would do.

```
class User
    def self.check(stuff) ...
```